# How can I do this transition in React Native?

Tags: react-native, transition

How can I do such transition in React Native?

https://streamable.com/e/667l2w

Is there any way to do that in the video like Instagram using FlashList or FlatList?

As you can see it is transitioning smoothly and never stops the video. So I don't think they are using react-navigation-shared-element or Reanimated 3 sharedTransitionTag prop.

But I did try this method anyway, just wanted to give it a chance but it's not being that smooth. So I am almost sure that there is no navigation.

So it should be a timeline element like instagram, and should translate to fullscreen when i tap, the other elements and footer + header should hidden as well.

There maybe a way to do this using CellRendererComponent prop but cannot figure out yet.
If anyone of you saw such complex animation or topic for how to do, so please share with me.

Thank you...